# Can everything that CSS Grid or Flex Box do be done with older CSS properties?

Tags: css

Can you do everything that CSS Grid or Flex box does with properties such as display, float, margin, position, overflow, etc ?

Edit: See my comment with @PeeyushKushwaha

Comment: Probably not... and even with some javascript help,  it's going to be a horrible set of hacks...

Comment: Why the down-votes? This question is interesting, if it can be done then you could write new CSS and compile it to do the same things with older CSS which works in more browsers

Comment: If you could do all of that with older CSS properties, there would have been no need to add them!

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Yes that is what I am thinking. If you could do the same things with older CSS then it works in more browsers. From my experience everytime I could have use a grid or flex box, I completed the task with older CSS properties. So far from my understanding Grid, and Flex make it easier to code.

Comment: No, you can't do everything they can with old CSS tech. There's a lot of articles out there, showing what Flexbox/CSS Grid can, that weren't possible before, just search for it

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, albeit with a long series of media queries and corresponding rules on position, margin, float, etc.

Flexbox and CSS Grid is meant to make UI presentation code as declarative as possible, so that you won't need to write the above series of rules imperatively, but instead allow the rendering engine to take care of laying out the components nicely.

Comment: Nope, you can't do everything what Flexbox/CSS Grid can with old tech. E.g. the `order` property has no old tech. variant.